# sound problem - output

Tags: drivers, sound, realtek, speakers, output

I'm using ipc2 i3 - [specs here](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/specifications/?model%5B%5D=IPC2-C4010-WACB-FMUSB3)

I'm not able to to hear anything but background noise -  and even that only while playing something.

No chance of physical damage - it was ok when i had windows 7, but in windows 10 it didn't work either - it said under "speakers" in sound manager "unplugged"

I believe it has something to do with the fact that my PC is able  to use s/pdif [as a default?], but I'm not sure how to change it in Ubuntu or windows. Could it be a BIOS setting?

I believe there is no "realtek sound manager" for Ubuntu. what are the options?

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal window and type:

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

You should hear a voice saying "Front Center". If it doesn't play the first time you run that command, try running it again as root:

```
sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

If it still doesn't play, that means there is a problem with your configuration. If the sound plays as root, but not as a regular user, then you need to add the user to the "audio" group, like this:

```
sudo addgroup <username> audio
```

and replace username with your actual username